# Which design pattern to use on Java workflow

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want to implement code for executing a workflow, but I'd like to avoid chains of if-else statements.
Which design pattern should I use? I looked at some of them, but couldn't find an appropriate one

Example of workflow.

```
A-> if(B) do C,
if(!B) do D-> E -> if(F) do G,
if(!H) do I-> J-> K
and so on..
```

Comment: What do you mean with `->`?

Comment: Suppose the workflow is an object. Then use state pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious choice to also consider here is [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). The problem with CoR in cases like this is sometimes you don't really know what the paths will be in advance, and so laying out all the possible paths can be really painstaking. Of course, you could use a Builder to construct the chains (remember all the Maze building examples from the Gang of Four).

The great thing about CoR is that your code does not become one big god object that has powerless pawns doing each 'step.'

Also, CoR affords a lot of flexibility. If the client comes and says 'OMG, there are two crucial steps missing,' someone can probably add them without destabilizing a lot of other stuff. Single-sourced orchestration is the archetypal god object antipattern, so maybe start with CoR and plan to evacuate if it runs out of rope.

Comment: I guess i will try this one.

Comment: I agree that [CoR](http://www.oodesign.com/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html) makes some sense, with a Handler for each line of your example. On the other hand, I disagree with its application in your case because by definition, the logic of the conditions is spread out (and encapsulated) in each Handler. It's not as clear to get the big picture as a centralized class.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement does exactly this. A carefully crafted `if, else if, else` will describe the logic in it's simplest form.

If you need the logic to be specified at runtime, e.g via a DSL, then you might want to create a tree structure of Decision and Command objects, where a Decision can be linked to multiple potential Commands, and a Command can be linked to a single subsequent Command. The tree would then be passed through an Executor that would start at the root of the tree and execute Decisions and Commands according to the input to the Decisions.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be imagined using [Messaging Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/eaipatterns.html) or [Pipes & Filter](http://www.eaipatterns.com/PipesAndFilters.html).

If you simply want a configurable workflow, it can be accomplished using [channels](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageChannel.html) and [routers](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageRouter.html) components.

Depending on nature and magnitude of you problem, you can either create your own mini simple implementation of above components or look for ready to use solutions like Spring Integration (which might have some learning curve to take care of).

Comment: That's fine. You can borrow the Pipes and filter approach and come up with something of your own.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but it looks like decisions will need to be made at some pt during processing.  If you don't want to use if..else ladders, you could create an abstract class with the following methods:

```
abstract protected boolean condition(<whatever params you need>)
abstract protected boolean doAction(<same params>)

public void execute(<params>) {

   if(condition(<params>)) {
      doAction(<params>)
   }
}
```

You can extend this abstract base class and create a rule class for each of these behaviors to manage the conditionals and actions that occur when a condition is satisfied.

You can then chain these classes together an execute them from a loop somewhere (passing the initial input (A) to the first rule in the list)  You can also add another abstract method and call that from an ELSE block after the IF in execute()

Basically, all this approach is doing is abstracting your If..Else ladder to a higher level.  Depending on the scope of your problem, it might in fact be simpler to do ifs and else.

If you give me more details, I can provide more thoughts!

Comment: well, is like you said..decisions.
But i want to avoid if..else chains.. Is like you said condtions and doActions, but my conditions and actions must be methods thatreturn something..